# Firebase responses 400

Tags: java, json, rest, firebase

I've got the following base structure:
[image]

And now I want to add some data to articles node. For example :

```
{"title":"Test","content":"Test text","keyWords":"1,2,3","date":"Aug 14, 2015 5:52:16 PM"}
```

Firebse REST API documentation says, that I should POST data, but log writes

> Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   https://$TEST-BASE.firebaseio.com/articles.json?auth=$TOKEN

`$TEST-BASE` and `$TOKEN` are valid parameters. I can clearly see the GET response. What is wrong? The code:
public class JSONTest {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        post("{\"title\":\"Test\",\"content\":\"Test text\",\"keyWords\":\"1,2,3\",\"date\":\"Aug 14, 2015 5:52:16 PM\"}", "https://<TEST-BASE>.firebaseio.com/articles.json?auth=<TOKEN>");


    }

    private static void post(String json, String urlString) {     

        OutputStreamWriter out = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
            httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    httpCon.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println(json);
            out.write(json);
            httpCon.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: did you end up finding an answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

I wish I had enough reputation points to just leave a comment =P , but I believe the reason why you're getting the 400 is because you're not sending your data to the right end-point. Try stripping the `.json` from the URL:

`https://<TEST-BASE>.firebaseio.com/articles?auth=<TOKEN>`

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403